# Using an instance of PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing several times in one document

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to place a PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing Object of the same image several times in an Excel file created with phpexcel - in other words this means I'd like to place one and the same image several times in one Excel file. Of course it is possible to create a new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing Object of the same image every time however the file size also grows every time.
So is it possible to place such an Object by reference or anything like that so that the file size will stay in an acceptable range?

Comment: Simple answer is no! You need a separate copy each time. What is defined as "acceptable range"?

Comment: Well, max 10MB. However I have to "reuse" every drawings about 50 times, which lets the file grow quickly.

Comment: I'd need to look at the Excel docs to identify how it would handle repetition of the same image, if it is possible to use any form of reference pointer. You might want to raise this as an issue in the PHPExcel issue log to remind me. There may not be a simple solution, so I can't make any promises: what format are you writing to?

Comment: Ok, I'll raise it in the issue log. For me, the format is not important. I'm currently writing Excel5 but would also use a newer format when allowing the image references.